# ClassNotFoundException in Chapter 3 of Java Game Development with LibGdx (Lee Stemkoski)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

The source code for the simple game introduced in Chapter 3 can be found [here](https://github.com/Apress/java-game-dev-LibGDX).

When I run it, I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Rock
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.mygdx.game.BaseActor.getList(BaseActor.java:565)
    at com.mygdx.game.LevelScreen.update(LevelScreen.java:36)
    at com.mygdx.game.BaseScreen.render(BaseScreen.java:37)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mygdx.game.BaseActor.getList(BaseActor.java:571)
    at com.mygdx.game.LevelScreen.update(LevelScreen.java:36)
    at com.mygdx.game.BaseScreen.render(BaseScreen.java:37)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The problem is in this method of the `Base Actor` class:

```
public static ArrayList<BaseActor> getList(Stage stage, String className)
{
    ArrayList<BaseActor> list = new ArrayList<BaseActor>();

    Class theClass = null;
    try
    {  theClass = Class.forName(className);  }
    catch (Exception error)
    {  error.printStackTrace();  }

    for (Actor a : stage.getActors())
    {
        if ( theClass.isInstance( a ) )
            list.add( (BaseActor)a );
    }

    return list;
}
```

There are several `Rock` objects in the `Stage`, but somehow this method fails to retrieve them. I'll appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Does className parameter contains package name something like libgdx.cp3.Rock, where do you use this method??

Comment: Is your function `getList` often called for different types of actors ? I mean, wouldn't it be more simple to create an `ArrayList<Rock>` for this class and add each `Rock` to it once created ?

Comment: @Abdullah Tellioglu I'm not sure I understand correctly. The method is used to get `Rock` objects from the `mainStage` and then another method checks for collisions with them.

Comment: @Xander This is the source code presented in the chapter. The method is used for different actors later on in the book.

Comment: Can someone help with this?